# Is it possible for MySQL to support both SSL and non-SSL at the same time?

Tags: mysql, ssl

We have an existing MySQL database with lots of clients connected to it.

We want to change MySQL to use secure connections (SSL/TLS).  However, we want to do this gracefully so that we don't have to redeploy all of our applications at the same time.

Ideally, we would like MySQL to support BOTH Secure and Non-secure connections (two different ports) for some window of time until all of our applications can convert over to SSL one at a time, on their own schedule.  Then once everyone has stopped using the non-secure port, we can shut that port off.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. MySQL uses TLS which is started after the connection is made and encryption can be optional or mandatory. You can set up TLS on the server and set it to be optional and when everyone has upgraded you can set it up as mandatory.

You don't need two separate ports since the encryption will be selected within the server protocol.

More information is in the [MySQL documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connections.html)

Comment: Oh!  I missed that!  I assumed it would be two different ports so I was searching the documentation for how to do it that way didn't didn't find it.   Thank you!  :)